# Exported blender obj file loses Pivot point

Tags: pivot, blender

I am using Blender 2.79. A new starter in blender but a Qt programmer. I am doing a car animation in QML 3D such that, I am exporting model from blender. I noted that, when I export, the position of blender objects is keeping well when import in QML. But the object's pivot point for rotation is loosing. I thought it is the problem with my QML stuff, but I opened the exported obj model in blender itself and noted that, the pivot point automatically reset to blender's orgin. That means, exported object's pivot point lost!

How can I solve the issue by keeping the exact pivot point while exporting?

Comment: obj files put the object origin at 0,0,0. Maybe clear the location in blender, export to obj and then position the object in your app.

Comment: I did it. When cleared the location and tried QML rotation, it is working awsome. But after i translated, It is rotating wrongly.

Comment: var m = Qt.matrix4x4();                                                                                                      m.rotate(userAngle, Qt.vector3d(0, 1, 0));                                                                 m.translate(Qt.vector3d(-8.19186, 4.2556, 12.2425));                                                  If I remove the last line, it is rotating well in orgin. But when I add the translation, that is added in third line, the rotation behaviour changes.